# How to chage a VM's os Disk

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a VM (Standard DS11 v2) on Azure about 2 - 3 weeks ago. It attached a premium disk which has extra price. (I did not know that when I created the VM.)

Now I want to change this disk to a standard disk. As I see, it is not possible to downgrade a premium disk to standard.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Attach a standard disk to my VM.
2. Copy premium disk to standard disk.
3. Make standard disk OS disk.
4. Detach premium disk.
5. Delete premium disk.,

How can I do that?

Also I am open to different solutions to my problem.

My OS is `Centos 7.2`.

Comment: OS disk is not SSD, no matter what VM you pick. If you have a SSD (additional data disk) attached to your VM, just attach a standard disk, copy everything and delete the SSD vhd using storage explorer ou blob explorer in Azure portal.

Comment: @BrunoFaria - that's false. When you create a *x*S-series VM, you may certainly choose to have an SSD OS disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could  not resize Ds series VM to D series VM.

Based on my knowledge, you could recreate your VM by using your VHD.

Please refer the following steps.

1. Stop and delete your VM but don't delete the VM's VHD.
2. Create a new `standard` storage account and blob container in the same resource group.
3. Copy VHD to the new storage account, you could use `Azcopy`.

`AzCopy /Source:https://shuidisks446.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /Dest:https://shuidiag102.blob.core.windows.net/vhds /SourceKey:sGqtdFHQWQWYyf2tRWGF5jkeAEubTp13AVaeTM25QogxXE+K0Ezq1ulcs18qGVPhCEp6ULdLLbKVa7fMbUvYZg== /DestKey:iCjeS+eegjkSJXHjH2UqCkqXnUPiCGvxaOG0Ad2LoPgUnvBoWl9wQJtC1jc//lOj4CF7khpLQe791P4QeyTY6Q== /Pattern:shui20161222141315.vhd`

More information about `Azcopy` please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

4. Use the VHD to create a D series VM. It is easy for you to recreate with existing VHD by using this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet)
5. Delete your Premium Storage Account.